# Fixing GPS lock that takes too long without installing a custom ROM

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, gps, huawei

My phone (Huawei Y300) takes a little under 10 minutes to get a GPS lock. This has been happening both in new locations as well as in and around my home (where it's on frequently).

What could be the problem that is causing this?

Are there any possible workarounds for this (and I don't mean custom ROMs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2). Then go to the app's `settings > gps sensors > auto-download AGPS data`, and set it to whatever you like. It also has a [Pro key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpstoolbox.pro), which unlocks other features.

> The main goal for the application is to assist you and all the other
>   applications on your device to get a GPS lock as fast as possible. It
>   is much better to know what is happening inside your phone than
>   staring cluelessly on a blinking notificaion icon and hoping that it
>   will stop blinking sooner or later. (Some people just simply enjoy
>   watching all the raw data ;)

Steps to follow if you have a non-locking GPS, from their [FAQ](http://mobiwia.com/gpsstatus/faq):

> - Menu / Tools / manage aGPS state.
> - Select 'Reset' to clear the internal state of the GPS.
> - Select 'Download' to re-download the assistance data. You will need an active internet connection at this step.
> - Close the GPS Status application for 10 seconds.
> - Go outside and find a spot where large part of the sky is visible.
> - Make sure you have the 'Keep the screen on' settings turned on (in Menu / Settings / Display & Tools'.
> - Let the program run and try to acquire your GPS position for at least 15 minutes.
>
> NOTES:
>
> - If the above steps do not resolve the GPS issue then you most likely have a hardware problem with the phone.
> - Certain phone cases block the GPS signal (remove the phone from it, if you are not sure.)
> - Certain windshields may block the GPS signal inside cars (those that have metallic coating to keep the heat out.)
> - Certain phones (usually CDMA) turn off the GPS chip if you put the phone into flight mode.
> - If you travel a long distance without turning on the GPS (i.e. flight) you can expect much longer fix times at your destination
>     initially.
> - Obviously you cannot expect the GPS to work in your basement! (yes I'm serious)

See if that improves the GPS lock.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the assisted GPS. Disabling it allows me to get a faster lock.

First, go to Settings then Location and turn off Google WiFi and mobile network location.  Just by turning that off doesn't disable the A-GPS but it should.

For the second step your phone will need to be rooted. Download Root Explorer from the Play store and use it to navigate to `/system/etc`. Find the file name gps.conf and rename it to anything that you want (I just renamed it to gpsxxx.conf).  When this file is not accessible by the system the A-GPS cannot work.

If you ever use an app like GPS Status after renaming the file, then it will redownload the A-GPS file, and you will need to go back into Root Explorer and rename or delete it

Comment: Assisted GPS isn't Google's invention - even dumbphones have it - and it can't be used to spy. It's just a way for GPS receivers to download the ephemeris data from the internet instead of the GPS signal.

Comment: Never said it was Googles invention. Everyone is entitled to there own opinion. Google is helping the nsa spy on the American people through their devices

Comment: Sure, you're entitled to your own opinion. But that doesn't mean we are also entitled to your opinion. Answers on this site are expected to be fact-based and to relate to the question. Your answer is much more useful now that it's focused on solving the problem.